# don't close form except a user is logged in

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform and want to make it unclosable if the user is not logged in ( userLogedIn = false ) and let it close only if the user is logged in ( userLogedIn = true ).

How can i do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the FormClosing event and set e.Cancel to the opposite (!userLoggedIn) of your userLoggedIn value, that will stop the form from closing.

Comment: +1; Additionaly, You can remove the ControlBox of the WinForm, and set the Property TopMost to true.